# BLOB error on Interactive Grid (Master Detail Form)

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I created master detail one page form on Apex 5.1, I have blob column in the detail when i am going to detial page im facing an error

```
Data type BLOB can not be converted to VARCHAR2!
Contact your application administrator.
Technical Info (only visible for developers)
is_internal_error: true
apex_error_code: WWV_FLOW_PLUGIN_UTIL.CANT_CONVERT_TO_VARCHAR2
component.type: APEX_APPLICATION_PAGE_REGIONS
component.id: 12860330874335917
component.name: Ticket Details
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't set blob in a page item directly, I think you want to display blob download link. Try to implement APEX_UTIL.GET_BLOB_FILE_SRC in-built APEX function.

Refer to Oracle doc for more information on this function --> [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E10513_01/apirefs.310/e12855/apex_util.htm#CHDICGDA)